# React gives Error: not supported error when I try and import local module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, import, export

I have a local module (speech.js) in my create-react-app src folder that is the google text to speech code on their website. I adjusted it to be an arrow function and use that specific export syntax.

```
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');

// Import other required libraries
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
export const main = async () => {
  // Creates a client
  const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();

  // The text to synthesize
  const text = "Hello world";

  // Construct the request
  const request = {
    input: {text: text},
    // Select the language and SSML Voice Gender (optional)
    voice: {languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL'},
    // Select the type of audio encoding
    audioConfig: {audioEncoding: 'MP3'},
  };

  // Performs the Text-to-Speech request
  const [response] = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
  // Write the binary audio content to a local file
  const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
  await writeFile('output.mp3', response.audioContent, 'binary');
  console.log('Audio content written to file: output.mp3');
};
```

What I'm not understanding is why this syntax isn't working in App.js.
`import {main} from './speech';`

I get the error, `Error: not support` and "4 stack frames were collapsed". Quite informative!

Does anyone know what the error could be here? I thought as long as I used es6 style imports and exports I wouldn't receive errors. Could this be due to the first require() statement of speech.js? Any help would be appreciated. I've felt like banging my head against the wall for the past 40 minutes.

Comment: Check babel preset. You can create .babelrc in root directory and add preset there.

Comment: @SameerRezaKhan Thanks for the reply. What is the preset supposed to be though?

Comment: If you have latest babel in your project, preset should be @babel/preset-react and @babel/preset-env

Comment: @SameerRezaKhan Am I supposed to do anything with this file? I create it in project root directory but I'm not sure how to effectively use this with my project.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the correct answer but I believe it has a good chance of being right. I believe that since node is just a runtime environment and not a part of the actual browser, you aren't able to use node modules with react (a frontend framework). The solution to this quandary would be to use something like electron.

Comment: what did the stack trace say? module fs not supported?